# How does VS Code remember trusted workspaces?

Tags: linux, macos, visual-studio-code

I would like to know how VS Code remembers which folders, repos and workspaces are "trusted". That is, where is it stored? In my personal case I want to know for Linux and Mac installations, but others may be interested in where it's stored in Windows too.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you run `code .` in a directory, vscode create a workspace (For ex. 504186ccde2f6d27a29b695ad0ceb3dc) in

```
$HOME/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage # Linux
$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage # MacOS
C:/Users/YourUser/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/workspaceStorage # Windows
```

In 504186ccde2f6d27a29b695ad0ceb3dc, there is a file state.vscdb (a sqlite database) which contains a key `workspace.trust.startupPrompt.shown`